# mySQL, multiple COUNT INNER JOINs with GROUP BY DATE()

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, inner-join

I have a table of install logs and I want to select from this table

1. number of installs PER DAY with status = 1
2. number of installs PER DAY with status = 0
3. number of installs PER DAY with status IN(0, 1)

Field created_utc is where I keep my install unix timestamp.

This is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `installs` (
  `created_utc` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1 - installed, 0 - deleted'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And this is my query, which does not work correctly (I'm selecting u.id as a crutch to execute inner joins... I'm totally lost)

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    count(pa.created_utc) AS installs_this_day, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(pa.created_utc, '%Y-%m-%d'))*1000 AS time_utc,
    count(pa2.created_utc) AS installs_active_this_day
FROM 
    users u
INNER JOIN installs AS pa ON pa.status = 0
INNER JOIN installs AS pa2 ON pa2.status = 1
WHERE u.id = 1
GROUP BY DATE(from_unixtime(pa.created_utc)), DATE(from_unixtime(pa2.created_utc))
```

This results in duplicates and incorrect counts.

```
1   45  1430280000000   45
1   36  1430280000000   36
1   117 1430280000000   117
1   72  1430280000000   72
1   36  1430280000000   36
1   531 1430280000000   531
1   144 1430280000000   144
1   36  1430280000000   36
1   18  1430280000000   18
1   27  1430280000000   27
1   9   1430280000000   9
```

Sample of installs table data

```
INSERT INTO `installs` (`created_utc`, `status`)
VALUES
    (1430320706, 0),
    (1430319316, 0),
    (1430311682, 0),
    (1430311506, 0),
    (1430311498, 0),
    (1430311498, 0),
    (1430311386, 0),
    (1430311370, 0),
    (1430311356, 0),
    (1430311272, 1),
    (1430278530, 1),
    (1430229788, 1);
```

Comment: What is the relation between the two tables `users` and `installs`?

Comment: No relation. I'm using users as a placeholder in my SELECT query. I know this is not smart, looking for a better way to execute inner joins. I do not need any data from users.

Comment: What do you like to get as result, can you type a sample output.

Comment: I'm looking to get an accurate count of install rows. Instead I'm getting duplicates and incorrect counts

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want conditional aggregation, not two or three joins.  Something like this:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(pa.created_utc, '%Y-%m-%d'))*1000 AS time_utc,
       sum(pa.status in (0, 1)) as total_installs,
       sum(pa.status = 0) as installs_status0,
       sum(pa.status = 1) as installs_status1
FROM installs pa
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(pa.created_utc, '%Y-%m-%d'))*1000;
```